# Download files from Android FTPServer

Tags: java, ftp

I wrote a simple java app, which would download files from FTP Server using  Apache Commons Net library and the server is located on android phone. I tried several settings and also several FTPServer apps, but I cannot get it work. The app just hangs after starting download. The only workaround I have found so far is to set a data timeout and then catch the exception and create a new client instance with a new connection to download the next file. Does anyone know how to get it right?

```
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(local);

    boolean downloaded = false;
    try {
        //InputStream retrieveFileStream = getFtpClient().retrieveFileStream(remoteFilePath);
        //new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
        FTPClient c = new FTPClient();
        c= new FTPClient();
        c.connect(host, port);
        c.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        c.setSoTimeout(1000 * 20);
        c.setDefaultTimeout(1000 * 20);
        c.login(user, pass);
        c.setBufferSize(1024 * 8);
        c.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        c.setDataTimeout(20 * 1000);
        downloaded = c.retrieveFile(remoteFilePath, outputStream);

        if (!downloaded) {
            String[] replyStrings = c.getReplyStrings();
            LOG.info("not downloaded code {} Messages {}", c.getReplyCode(), Arrays.toString(replyStrings));
            local.delete();
        } else {
            LOG.info("file was downloaded");
        }
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
        if (!(iOException.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException)) {
            LOG.info("Caught iOException do shut down"  + iOException.getMessage());
            logoutAndDisconnect();
        } else {
            LOG.info("Caught SocketTimeoutException assuming file was downloaded " + iOException.getMessage());
            downloaded = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("ERROR: ", e.getMessage(), e);
        logoutAndDisconnect();
    } finally {
        outputStream.close();
    }
    return downloaded;
}
```

A similar problem is described here http://www.egeek.me/2012/11/22/downloading-a-file-via-ftp-in-android/, but I'm im local network

Answer (score 0):

It was DroidWall on the phone blocking the connection. Disabling it or allowing kernel connections in general solves the issue.